# How to get date from Date Picker and show in the table? Material-UI. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I use Date Picker component from Material-UI for React JS. I want to show the selected date on the table. A date is an object and I have an error when trying to show in a table row. How to do this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import { Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn } from 'material-ui/Table';

export default class AddTaskDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { controlledDate: {} };
    this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeDate = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      controlledDate: date,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker hintText="Date" value={this.state.controlledDate} onChange={this.handleChangeDate}/>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.state.controlledDate}</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date that is sent to the `handleChangeDate` handler is of type `object`. You need to convert it to a date string in order to render inside the `TableRowColumn`.

```
export default class AddTaskDialog extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { controlledDate: new Date() };
 this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);
}

handleChangeDate = (event, date) => {
  this.setState({
    controlledDate: date
  });
};

// INSIDE RENDER
<TableRowColumn>{this.state.controlledDate.toDateString()}</TableRowColumn>
```

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(typeof date);
   
console.log(date.toDateString());
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I have error in console "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `string` supplied to `DatePicker`, expected `object`."

Comment: Try the updated snippet. Convert to date string in the render method directly because `DatePicker` seems to be expecting a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the state in the TableRow.

```
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { controlledDate: '' };
         this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);
    }

    ...

    render() {
       ...

       <TableRow>
           TableRowColumn>{this.state.controlledDate || New Date(Date.now())}</TableRowColumn>
       </TableRow>
    }
```

Comment: Still error.
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `TableRowColumn`, expected a ReactNode."

Comment: Why are you initially declaring the date state as an object? I'm guessing it is a string? You also need to check if there's a date and display something else (maybe the current one otherwise). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
{this.state.controlledDate}
```

not `{this.controlledDate}`

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.